# Add class to clicked th and corresponding td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I would like to add a class to a clicked `th` element and all corresponding `td` elements. The class must be removed from both `th` and `td` when clicking another `th`.

I am attempting to match the index of the `th` to the `td` with:

```
$('th').click(function () {
  var indexOf = $(this).index();
  $('.sortable').removeClass('sortable');
  $(this).addClass('sortable');
  $('td:nth-child('+indexOf+')').addClass('sortable');
});
```

Dummy HTML

```
<table class="data">
  <tr>
    <th>Entry Header 1</th>
    <th>Entry Header 2</th>
    <th>Entry Header 3</th>
    <th>Entry Header 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Entry First Line 1</td>
    <td>Entry First Line 2</td>
    <td>Entry First Line 3</td>
    <td>Entry First Line 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Entry Line 1</td>
    <td>Entry Line 2</td>
    <td>Entry Line 3</td>
    <td>Entry Line 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Entry Last Line 1</td>
    <td>Entry Last Line 2</td>
    <td>Entry Last Line 3</td>
    <td>Entry Last Line 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you understand the difference between your two uses of `.index()`? The problem is clear once you know the difference.

Comment: ...and you don't need to give "starting code". That implies that you just want someone to finish it for you. Give a legitimate attempt at implementing your feature, and if it doesn't work, describe in detail what went wrong.

Comment: I was just thinking that an index solution might work. I guess it doesn't. I was attempting to match the index number of the `th` to the `td`

Comment: An index solution will work. But you need to understand how `.index()` works. To do that, you'll need to read the docs. There are at least 3 different ways of using `.index()`, and you're using two of them together in a way that won't produce the result you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$('th').click(function () {
    var indexOf = $(this).index();
    $('th,td').not('td:nth-child(' + (indexOf + 1) + '), th:nth-child(' + (indexOf + 1) + ')').removeClass('sortable')
    $(this).add('td:nth-child(' + (indexOf + 1) + ')').toggleClass('sortable');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bnnm6cLv/1/)**

Comment: Ahhh i was close! Thanks!